# Inequality for supremums of functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

We have the reverse triangle inequality:

$|x-y| \geq ||x| - |y||$

Let $f, g \in \mathbb{R}^I$ for some interval $I$. Fix $x \in I$.

Do we have that sup$\{f(x)-g(x)\} \geq$ sup$\{f(x)\}$ - sup$\{g(x)\}$ ?

P.S. I'm asking this because I believe I need that to proof that $(X,$$d_{\infty,\infty})$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** For every $x\in I$, we have
$$ f(x) = \big(f(x)-g(x)\big) + g(x) \leq \sup (f-g)(I)+\sup g(I).$$
Taking the supremum over $x\in I$ thus gives
$$ \sup f(I) \leq \sup (f-g)(I)+\sup g(I).$$
Now re-arrange to get
$$\sup (f-g)(I) \geq \sup f(I) - \sup g(I),$$
as requested.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\sup_{\Omega} f(x) - \sup_{\Omega} g(x) \le
\sup\limits_{\Omega}(f(x)-g(x)) \le 
\sup_{\Omega} f(x) - \inf_{\Omega} g(x).
$$
This assumes that the domain of both functions is $\Omega$.

Comment: The inequality provided is true, but I think the answer is yes, see my proof.

Comment: Yes. "No" in my answer referred to the inequality in the title. :)

Comment: Agreed, @Alex, the title makes no sense actually.